# Lua requests free on NULL ptr regularly

Tags: c++, lua, malloc

I have a rather large lua 5.4 script running (with no problems) inside a C++ lua embedder. I also used my own l_alloc implementation. Whenever it is called, I print what lua requests:

```
static void *l_alloc(void *ud, void *ptr, size_t osize, size_t nsize) {
    fprintf(stdout, "[LUA_ALLOC] ptr %p, osize %d, nsize %d\n", ptr, osize, nsize);
```

Sometimes the result is:

```
[LUA_ALLOC] ptr 0x0, osize 0, nsize 0
```

Quoting the lua 5.4 documentation:

> When nsize is zero, the allocator must behave like free and return
> NULL.

So Lua wants me to call free(NULL) just for fun? I dont see why this would happen.

What I tried to understand the issue:

1. Use different implementations for the realloc used by l_alloc
2. Check if null pointer is ever returned (when nsize != 0) by realloc (so by alloc). This is not the case. This would likely lead to a segfault anyway.
3. I tried to find any action that leads to such a request. I was not able to find any. My main thoughts were that it might happen if I create an empty table, empty string or something, but it doesnt.

Any idea why this happens?

Comment: The documentation explains the requirements for the allocator and even gives an example function. I'm not sure what your question is.

Comment: @RetiredNinja My question was "why". The example function and documentation is nice, but it does not answer my question that realloc with ptr = NULL and nsize = 0 leads to a free(NULL) which does nothing.

Comment: Perhaps you could ask this in the Lua mailing list. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In Lua 5.4.4, the first time this happens is in `luaH_resize` at ltable.c, line 571, when Lua is starting, opening the basic library.

```
newarray = luaM_reallocvector(L, t->array, oldasize, newasize, TValue)
```

At the moment, `t->array` hasn't been created yet and is NULL.

Comment: Isnt newarray afterwards still null? Not sure if I understand you correctly, but nsize should be also 0 then (which was the point of my question). This would need to newarray being still NULL after this line. I dont see the point of this line then. It should even cause the next line in ltable.c to act as if the allocation failed:
`if (l_unlikely(newarray == NULL && newasize > 0)) {  /* allocation failed? */`